# MethodError, despite being (somehow) defined

Tags: julia

I am trying to do something like this:

```
function outer(x::Array{Float64}, y::Array{Float64}=nothing)
    if (y == nothing)
        function inner(y::Array{Float64})
            return x .* y
        end
        return inner
    else
        return x .+ y
    end
end

outer([2.], [3.])  # to return 5, works
outer([2.])([3.])  # to return 6, fails.
```

`outer([2.], [3.])` works just fine.

**The problem** is that `outer([2.])([3.])` raises a `MethodError` stating:

```
MethodError: no method matching outer(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Void)
Closest candidates are:
  outer(::Array{Float64,N} where N) at In[1]:2
  outer(::Array{Float64,N} where N, ::Array{Float64,N} where N) at In[1]:2

Stacktrace:
 [1] outer(::Array{Float64,1}) at ./In[1]:2
 [2] include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:522
```

The weird bit is that under `Closest candidates`, the single-argument `outer(::Array{Float64,N} where N)` is the first candidate. So why does it not work with the single argument?

Note: `outer([2.], )([3.])`, `outer([2.], nothing)([3.])`, `outer([2.], [nothing])([3.])` all produce the same (similar) error.

---

This can be reproduced using a single argument function too:

```
function outer(y::Array{Float64}=nothing)
    if (y == nothing)
        function inner(y::Array{Float64})
            return y .* y
        end
        return inner
    else
        return y .+ y
    end
end

outer([2.])
1-element Array{Float64,1}:
 4.0

outer()([3.])
MethodError: no method matching outer(::Void)
Closest candidates are:
  outer() at In[6]:2
  outer(::Array{Float64,N} where N) at In[6]:2
  outer(::Array{Float64,N} where N, ::Array{Float64,N} where N) at In[1]:2

Stacktrace:
 [1] outer() at ./In[6]:2
 [2] include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:522
```

And again, there is a zero-argument function `outer()` listed first in the `Closest candidates` list!

---

---

Basically, the above example is a MWE representing a log-sum/likelihood evaluation, where `x` is the `data` and `y` is the `parameter` of a model. I am trying to return a function in the parameter of the model to optimise using MLE, or return the log-sum if the parameter is passed.

In this analogy, `outer` computes log-sum, given data and parameter, or returns `inner` as a function of the parameter, which can be optimised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reproduce this with simply:

```
f(x::Float64=nothing) = x
f()
```

When you add `= nothing` that sets nothing as a default argument. And also adds `f()` as a method. But when you call `f()` then julia will try to run `f(nothing)` as `nothing` is your default argument. That will then error as `nothing` is of type `Void` and *you asserted that the argument must be* `Float64`.

For example you *could* (but shouldn't) use `f(x::Union{Float64,Void}=nothing) = x` to get around this. But it'd be much better to use a `Nullable` which is exactly for interacting with a value that may or may not exist.

Read more about Nullables [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#man-nullable-types-1) or type `?Nullable` in the REPL.

---

## Edit by OP

### MWE:

```
function outer(x::Array{Float64}, y=Nullable{Array{Float64}}())
    if isnull(y)
        function inner(y::Array{Float64})
            return x .* y
        end
        return inner
    else
        return x .+ y
    end
end

outer([2.])([3.])  # Produces 6,
outer([2.], [3.])  # Produces 5.
```

Works as expected.

Comment: I looked at the `Nullable` type. However, I could not get it to work in the function. Can you post a MWE using the `Nullable` type to complete your answer to the question (and so that I can accept your answer, if you can make it work)?

Comment: Actually, I just figured out how to get `Nullable` to work. I was being so silly trying `y::Nullable{Array{Float64}}=nothing` (which resulted in the same error), `y::Nullable{Array{Float64}}()` (which raises an `ArgumentError`), and `y::Nullable{Array{Float64}}`. The solution is **`y=Nullable{Array{Float64}}()`**, because when I reread the documentation just now, I realised `Nullable{Array{Float64}}()` is a value, and not a type (well, it is a value of the specified type). Would you rather I edit your answer with the MWE?

Comment: Sorry I'm on my phone can do tomorrow morning. FYI this quickest solution would just be to define outer(x) and outer (x, y) separately rather than rely on the default arguments and Nullables. I think that's appropriate for your use case?

Comment: as in have either part of your `if ... else` condition as a separate method taking one or two arguments respectively

Comment: It would work, but I come from `Python`, and using two overloaded functions is an ugly solution to Pythoners! Since you are unavailable to include the MWE, I took the liberty of editing your answer, and then accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Readability counts** so maybe you have to reconsider define 2 methods explicitly (and simple as it is in Julian way):

```
outer(x::Array{Float64}, y::Array{Float64}) = x .+ y
outer(x::Array{Float64}) = y -> x .* y
```

Comment: Yes, true, this does look good. But like I mention in the question, this is actually to compute the likelihood and return a function that can be optimised or return the likelihood value. The function is not as simple as the MWE in the question. It is much more complex, with quite a bit of data processing, parameter handling, and other optimization stuff. If I use two functions, I'd end up duplicating about 30 lines of code, which takes it far from readable, and understandable. Therefore, no. Thank you for the insight into the Julian way.

Comment: You could probably 30 lines of code put into 3-rd function. (and use `@inline` hint) ;) But I understand what are you talking about! :) BTW look for example at `.../julia/base/abstractarray.jl` (`@edit vcat((1 for i in 1:2)...)`) - there are plenty of oneliners.